# Let $\mathcal{E}(\lambda)\neq\emptyset$. Why doesn't $V_\lambda$ satisfy the existence of a Reinhardt?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

$\mathcal{E}(\lambda)\neq\emptyset$ if and only if there is a nontrivial elementary embedding $j:V_\lambda\rightarrow V_\lambda$.

My question is why this can even be consistent. A function $j:A\rightarrow B$ for $A,B\subseteq V_\lambda$ is an elementary embedding in $V_\lambda$ if and only if $j$ is a function in $V_\lambda$ (which is true), and for every first-order $\varphi$:

- $V_\lambda\models\forall a_0\in A((A\models\varphi(a_0))\Leftrightarrow(\exists b_0\in B((a_0,b_0)\in j\land B\models\varphi(b_0)))$
- $V_\lambda\models\forall a_0,a_1\in A((A\models\varphi(a_0,a_1))\Leftrightarrow(\exists b_0,b_1\in B((a_0,b_0)\in j\land (a_1,b_1)\in j\land B\models\varphi(b_0,b_1)))$
- ...

However, it seems like this is true if and only if $j:A\rightarrow B$ is an actual elementary embedding.

**First question: Why isn't the rank of every I3 cardinal a model of the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal?**

**Second question: Given a sufficiently large cardinal $\kappa$ (inaccessible, perhaps), when does $V_\kappa$ satisfy that $j$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding for some $j\subseteq V_\kappa$?**

Comment: $\lambda$ is the supremum of the critical sequence, so replacement fails in $V_\lambda$ for the language $\{\in,j\}$. If you allow the possibility that $\lambda$ is instead the successor of the supremum of the critical sequence, then $V_\lambda$ is not even a model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Comment: The second question is meaningless as stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacement fails in $V_\lambda$, since $f(n)=j^n(\kappa)$ is definable and with domain $\omega$, but it isn't a set in $V_\lambda$.

So yes, $V_\lambda$ satisfies "some set theory + choice + there is a Reinhardt cardinal". But it doesn't satisfy enough set theory to prove Kunen's theorem. Specifically, there isn't enough Replacement going on in $V_\lambda$ for the proof to work.

Comment: The notion of Reinhardt cardinal is only meaningful in a language where replacement holds for formulas involving the embedding, so I think it is not appropriate to say that $V_\lambda $ satisfies "there is a Reinhardt cardinal". (Also, $V_\lambda $ satifies $\mathsf{ZFC}$, not just "some set theory".)

Comment: @Andres: How do you get Replacement in $V_\lambda$?, and exactly since Reinhardt is something you pretty much need $j$ in your language to even formulate, this destroys Replacement in ZFC(j), and ergo "some set theory" and not "set theory". But you're right, and I shouldn't be so cavalier with axioms when the language is a bit murky.

Comment: $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is formulated just in $\{\in\}$ so $j$ does not matter here. To see that it holds in $V_\lambda$, note that $V_{\kappa_0}\prec V_{\kappa_1}$ (by Tarski-Vaught, for instance), and elementarity then gives you that in fact $V_{\kappa_n}\prec V_{\kappa_{n+1}}$ for all $n$, so also they are elementary in their union.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can't someone formulate Reinhardt in NBG without limitation of size or some other second-order set theory?

Comment: @KeithMillar Yes, as discussed in chapter 1 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.06.001).