# Models of ZF + Reinhardt (Final part to series of questions)

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

So, in the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539115/followup-to-last-question-when-is-f-an-elementary-embedding-in-l), I got an answer to what the minimum requirement for an inner model of the existence of a Reinhardt is due to Andrés E. Caicedo. However, I did not get an answer to the first question I asked, most likely because I didn't show the information required to complete it.

So, here is my "proof" that $0^{\#}$ can't exist:

Let $j:L\rightarrow L$ be a nontrivial elementary embedding.

It is said that the existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ to itself can be expressed as a first-order theory with an added constant symbol $j$. **However, I could not find this theory. So, I attempted to create my own. I believe this is why the proof fails.**

I asserted that $M$ a standard transitive model of ZF satisfies the existence of such an embedding iff there is some $f:M\rightarrow M$ such $\langle M;\in, f\rangle$ satisfies the following schema:

1. $\exists x(f(x)\neq x)$
2. For every formula $\varphi$ which does not contain a function symbol:

   - $\forall x(\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(f(x)))$
   - $\forall x_0,x_1(\varphi(x_0,x_1)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(f(x_0),f(x_1)))$
   - ...
   - $\forall x_0,x_1...x_n(\varphi(x_0,x_1...x_n)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(f(x_0),f(x_1),...f(x_n)))$
   - ...

So, let's check if this holds for $\langle L;\in,j\rangle$:

1. $j$ is nontrivial, so $\exists x\in L(j(x)\neq x)$ by definition of nontriviality. Of course, this is equivalent to $\langle L;\in,j\rangle\models\exists x(f(x)\neq x)$. So, $\langle L;\in,j\rangle$ satisfies this.
2. Let $\varphi$ be a formula which does not contain a function symbol.

   - Because $j$ is elementary: $$\forall x\in L(L\models\varphi[x]\Leftrightarrow L\models\varphi[j(x)])$$ 
     $$\forall x\in L(L\models(\varphi[x]\Leftrightarrow \varphi[j(x)]))$$
     $$\forall x\in L(\langle L;\in,j\rangle\models(\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow \varphi(f(x))))\text{ because }f\text{ is interpreted as }j $$
     $$\langle L;\in,j\rangle\models\forall x\in L(\varphi(x)\Leftrightarrow\varphi(f(x)))$$
   - This could be shown to hold for more quantification with the same method.

Therefore, it seems as though $L$ satisfies the existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding, which is obviously false. **Where am I wrong? If I am wrong because I stated the scheme incorrectly, why?**

Comment: It does not seem like you have done anything so far. You say: Assume that $j\!:L\to L$ is elementary (in the language $\{\in\}$) and nontrivial. OK. So?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think Keith is arguing that $(L; \in, j)$ should constitute a model of the first-order theory which Kunen (appropriately translated) showed is inconsistent. Of course it doesn't, but I think that's what he's trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. He did not state that $j$ is amenable, which as discussed in the previous question is what matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite right: the problem is **when you define the theory in question**. You show that $(L; \in, j)$ is a *(fine, proper class)* model of a certain theory, and then claim that that is the theory Kunen showed was inconsistent; but the problem is that the theory Kunen showed was inconsistent was *not* just "ZFC + $j$ is an elementary embedding."

The actual first-order theory (call it "ZFC$_{elem}$," I don't know if it actually has a name) that Kunen showed is inconsistent is *much stronger* than what you've written, the difference being the extension of the separation/replacement schemes to include formulas *in the new language* (that is, including the added function symbol). Going back to the usual Kunen inconsistency, we see that we can't have $\{j(\xi): \xi<\lambda\}$ (where $\lambda=j^{(\omega)}(crit(j))$ is the first $j$-fixed point above the critical point) be an element of $L$, so $(L; \in, j)$ does **not** satisfy the separation scheme for formulas with $j$ as a parameter.

**Note that this is exactly the amenability issue raised in your previous question, I'm just phrasing it here in terms of the axioms of the theory involved since I think that might be clearer.**

Here's the precise definition of ZFC$_{elem}$ and statement of the "first-order Kunen inconsistency":

> Let $\Sigma=\{\in, f\}$ be a language gotten by adding a unary function symbol to the language of set theory. Let ZFC$^f$ be the theory in this language consisting of: *(i)* the usual ZFC axioms, *(ii)* a scheme (as you've written) asserting that $f$ is an elementary embedding from the universe to itself, and *(iii)* expanded replacement/separation schemes covering all formulas in the expanded language. Then ZFC$_{elem}$ is inconsistent.

So if you could get a model of ZFC$_{elem}$ from the assumption that $0^\sharp$ exists, then you would indeed have disproved the existence of $0^\sharp$; however, the structure $(L;\in, j)$ is *not* a  model of ZFC$_{elem}$ since it doesn't satisfy the expanded separation/replacement schemes (part (iii)).

---

As an aside, what I've written above is overkill; Kunen needed much less than the *full* separation/replacement schema extended to the new language. But there's no reason to go into that at the moment.

Comment: Exactly, that's how I know my proof is wrong. Maybe I didn't make my question exactly clear, but I meant to ask how my proof is false (i.e. not a proof), because it seems like I disproved the existence of $0^{\#}$. That is, where exactly did I make a mistake in my proof?

Comment: @KeithMillar Ah, I misunderstood. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ah ok, so for any transitive standard model M of ZF, $\langle M;\in,f\rangle$ satisfies Kunen's version of $\text{ZFC}_{elem}$ for some $f$ iff $M$ satisfies the existence of a Reinhardt embedding?

Comment: @KeithMillar (Ignoring the ZF/ZFC issue) What do you mean by "a Reinhardt embedding"? Would you say $L$ has a Reinhardt embedding (assuming $0^\sharp$ exists)? (Note that for *no* $j$ does $(L; \in, j)$ satisfy ZFC$_{elem}$.) In particular, if by "Reinhardt embedding" you just mean a nontrivial elementary embedding into itself, the answer is **no**.

Comment: @KeithMillar The key word (as always here) is "amenable." $(M; \in, f)$ satisfies ZFC$_{elem}$ for some $f$ iff $M$ admits an *amenable* elementary embedding into itself. So - assuming what you mean by "Reinhardt embedding" is "amenable embedding" - the answer to your question is "yes." (And, rephrasing what has already been said for possible clarity: while $0^\sharp$ does imply that there is an elementary embedding of $L$ into itself, it *doesn't* imply that there is an amenable elementary embedding of $L$ into itself.)

Comment: I mean $M$ satisfies the existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself. Is there some known way to first-order axiomatize the existence of such an embedding over models of $\text{ZF}$? (Sorry for the ZF/ZFC issue, can't edit comment again)

Comment: @KeithMillar If all you care about is a nontrivial elementary embedding of $M$ into itself, then the weaker theory ZFC + "$j$ is an elementary embedding" (the one you essentially describe in your question) works: $M$ admits a nontrivial elementary embedding into itself iff it has an expansion (by that embedding) to a model of that theory. However, this theory doesn't have any real connection with the Kunen inconsistency, which is really all about amenability.

Comment: I care about $M$ being a model of the existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself. My bad if this was worded badly. However, what is amenable mean for non-inner models of ZF?

Comment: (Note that this is really *second-order*: we have a theory $T$ and we're saying $(M; \in)$ has a nontrivial elementary embedding if $(M;\in, j)\models T$ **for some function** $j$.)

Comment: "$M$  being a model of the existence of a nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into itself." It's a bit unclear to me what this means, but I think you're just asking for a sufficient condition for a transitive model of ZF(C) to have a nontrivial elementary embedding into itself - yes? If so, then "can be expanded to the weak theory ZFC + '$j$ is elementary and nontrivial'" (which is again vastly weaker than ZFC$_{elem}$) does the job, but this theory has no real connection to Kunen's argument (since the $j$ in question isn't guaranteed to be amenable, and indeed in general can't be).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69422/discussion-between-keith-millar-and-noah-schweber).