# Is it provable in ZF that there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $\pi: V\to V$?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Is it open whether it can be proved in $ZF$ alone that if $\pi:V\to M$ is a nontrivial elementary embedding, then $M\not=V$?

Comment: What are $V, M, \pi$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem for what is and isn't known.

Comment: @JCAA As usual $V$ is the set-theoretic universe and (as is usual with this topic) $M$ is some inner model; $\pi$, meanwhile, is explicitly declared to be a nontrivial elementary embedding so there's no question there.

Comment: There is no $M$ in the title.

Comment: @JCAA So? In this context it is standard to use $M$ to refer to an arbitrary inner model. It doesn't need to be used in the title. (Incidentally the title asks whether there is no nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$, the body asks whether every nontrivial elementary embedding of $V$ into some $M$ must have $M\not=V$ - they're basically the same question, differently phrased.)

Comment: I am not familiar with the area, If the OP does not want non-specialists to view the question, (s)he should say so. If (s)he wants me to understand it, (s)he should give more details. And of course the questions in the title and the body should be the same and if these are not the same, an explanation should be given why it is so.

Comment: @JCAA I'm sorry but I think that's a far too restrictive response. I don't demand that questions about e.g. algebraic geometry be written so as to be understandable to me, since I don't have the relevant background. I think this question definitely could use more motivation, but is no less self-contained than any of the other countless higher-level questions on this site. (And the title/body question are basically the same, per my previous comment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short version is that you're asking whether **Reinhardt cardinals** are consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$, and this is totally open right now. Indeed, even stronger large cardinal hypotheses are currently not known to be inconsistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (e.g. super-Reinhardt, Berkeley, etc.).

---

The longer version is that what you've written doesn't actually make sense in the rather restricted language of $\mathsf{ZF}$, since we can't refer to (let alone quantify over) class functions from the universe to itself. We can handle this in one of a few different ways:

- Work in an appropriate class theory which is a  conservative extension of $\mathsf{ZF}$, as $\mathsf{NBG}$ is to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. This is in some ways the most natural approach, and matches if I recall correctly how the argument was originally phrased ("$\mathsf{NBG}$ proves that there is no nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$").
- Look at the "set-sized" version of Reinhardt cardinals, namely critical points of nontrivial elementary embeddings of the form $V_{\lambda+2}\rightarrow V_{\lambda + 2}$. (Note that the "combinatorial core" of the Kunen inconsistency argument is in fact a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof that there is no nontrivial elementary embedding from $V_{\lambda+2}$ into $V_{\lambda+2}$ for any $\lambda$.) While this shift may seem unnatural, note that it's actually quite useful in that it reveals new concepts as being of potential interest: e.g. in my opinion it's really only in light of the $V_{\lambda+2}$-analysis that the [rank-into-rank cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-into-rank) emerge as natural objects.
- Work in a version "$\mathsf{ZF(j)}$" of $\mathsf{ZF}$ which has a new constant naming a putative nontrivial elementary embedding from $V$ into itself and try to derive a contradiction. The key subtlety here is to get the axioms of this theory right - it's crucial that we extend the Separation and Replacement schemes to formulas involving $j$. (Specifically, the *non*-extended version of $\mathsf{ZFC}(j)$ is consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "$0^\sharp$ exists," which [can look like](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542122/28111) a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of the nonexistence of $0^\sharp$.)

Whichever approach we choose, though, the answer is: **it's currently open**.

Comment: In the case of $V_{\lambda+2}\to V_{\lambda+2}$, I think an apt name for the critical point is a *Kunen cardinal*. Also, recently Farmer Schultzenberg posted https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.01077 with a significant new breakthrough on this, showing that I0 implies the existence of Kunen cardinals in an inner model. Which is pretty amazing.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment since Noah already gave a good answer, but it is a positive result which might be of interest nonetheless and it doesn't fit into a comment.

Another approach not mentioned (for good reasons, as you'll see below) in his answer is that of only working with definable elementary embeddings $j\colon V\prec V$, that is $j$ such that there is a formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ and parameter $p$ such that $\varphi(x,y,p)$ holds if and only if $j(x)=y$ (in other words $\varphi(-,-,p)$ defines the graph of $j$). Given such a formula it is clear that domain and range of $j$ are also definable, it is less clear that the notions "$\varphi(-,-,p)$ is an elementary embedding" and "its range is an inner model" are definable, but it can be done, and if $\varphi(-,-,p)$ defines an elementary embedding the notions of the embedding being nontrivial and its critical point being $\kappa$ are also expressible.

**Theorem (Suzuki, ZF):** There is no definable nontrivial $j\colon V\prec V$. (and the proof is much easier than the full proof of Kunen's inconsistency for $\mathsf{ZFC}$).

Note that this theorem is really a schema of theorems, one for each formula $\varphi$, saying that there is no parameter $p$ such that $\varphi(-,-,p)$ defines an elementary embedding.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\varphi(x,y,z)$ defines an elementary embedding for some parameter $p$. Assuming the definability of the notions expressed above the class $$\{\lambda\in\sf{Ord}\mid \lambda\text{ is the critical point of $\varphi(-,-,\bar{p})$ for some parameter $\bar{p}$}\}$$
is also definable, and so is its minimum, call it $\kappa$. But then the property of $\kappa$ that "$\kappa$ is the least possible critical point of an elementary embedding defined by $\varphi$" is expressible by a first order formula, and so by elementarity $j(\kappa)$ has the same property, contradicting $j(k)>\kappa$. $\square$

Also note that pretty much the same argument really shows that the property of being Reinhardt is not a first-order property, in contrast to other large cardinal notions which have second order definitions that are equivalent to first order ones (a cardinal $\kappa$ is measurable iff it is the critical point of an embedding $j\colon V\prec M$ (second order) iff it has a $\kappa$ complete nonprincipal ultrafilter (first order) and so on)

Comment: Your argument for Suzuki's theorem is somewhat misleading in my opinion, since it glosses over the key point: that in fact "$\kappa$ is the least possible critical point of an elementary embedding defined by $\varphi$" is first-order expressible, and it takes [a bit of cleverness](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2586799.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A67b566a1d9db1d62356903780d035681) to get around that.