# Elementary Embeddings of Transitive Models of ZFA

Tags: set-theory, alternative-set-theories

My question is related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289643/does-every-elementary-embedding-jv-to-v-in-zfa-arise-from-a-self-injection-o

Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFCA (ZFC with atoms) and suppose that $j: M \rightarrow M$ is an elementary embedding that moves some ordinal in $M$.

Let $A^M$ be the set of atoms in $M$ and let us assume that $A^M$ is NOT a set in $M$ (see Noah's answer if we assume $A^M$ is a set). What do we know about $j$'s action on $A^M$? In particular, is it possible that $j \upharpoonright A^M$ is the identity map?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, what is it to say j is amenable to the model?

Comment: @user123 See the link in the first part of my answer. Basically, if $N\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $j:N\rightarrow N$ is an elementary embedding which moves some ordinal then $j$ must be "very nasty" from the perspective of $N$ - essentially, $j$ must witness $M\not=V$ in the sense that there must be a way to build given $j$ a set not in $N$. For example, if we take $N=V$ then trivially everything is amenable over $N$ and so the statement simplifies to: "There are no nontrivial elementary embeddings $V\rightarrow V$" (which is the Kunen inconsistency).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I see. So I'm not assuming that j is amenable to M. And in fact, the model M I had in mind is just a countable transitive model of ZFCA.

Answer (score 1):

First, to forestall a reasonable concern readers might have, note that since $M$ is not assumed to contain $V$ as its "pure" part the Kunen inconsistency does not apply. For example, [it doesn't prevent elementary embeddings of $L$ into itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542122/28111). In more technical language, as Asaf Karagila comments above there is no well-founded model of $\mathsf{ZFCA}$ with an elementary self-embedding moving some ordinal which is amenable over that model.

---

Now on to the actual question:

We have a lot of freedom here. For example, suppose $M$ satisfies "There is a bijection between $A$ and $\omega$." In this case since elementary embeddings can't move $\omega$ we do in fact get $j[A]=A$: consider the action of $j$ on some bijection $f:A\rightarrow\omega$. (This is basically the same argument as that $M\cap \omega_1$ is downwards-closed whenever $M$ is an elementary submodel of $V$.) And this generalizes to any model where (in $M$) the set of atoms is in bijection with some cardinal $<crit(j)$. On the other hand, basically for the same reason if $M\models\vert A\vert>crit(j)$ then $f[A]\subsetneq A$.

So that gives a complete description of what happens if, from the perspective of $M$, the set $A$ of atoms is in bijection with some "pure" set. This of course leaves open the question of what happens if there is no bijection in $M$ between $A$ and any pure set; I'm not sure what things look like in that case.

Comment: I'm confused. In a model of ZFCA, the pure sets are not definable? And if they are, wouldn't an elementary embedding will necessarily be an embedding of pure sets to pure sets?

Comment: @AsafKaragila The class of pure sets is definable in $\mathsf{ZFCA}$: they're the sets whose transitive closures don't contain any atoms. (Or if you prefer, define it as $\bigcup_{\alpha\in Ord}V_\alpha$.) And so yes, an elementary embedding will be an elementary embedding of the pure sets into themselves, but so what? We're not assuming amenability.

Comment: I think that at this point in the broadcast I must insist that when talking about non-amenable embedding, this needs to be mentioned explicitly. At least in the context where AC is present (I'd give it a pass if we were talking about ZFA).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I disagree - we talk all the time about elementary embeddings $L\rightarrow L$.

Comment: Yes, where the context is very very clearly taking place in larger universe, where the embeddings are in fact amenable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure what you mean. In that larger universe the original embeddings aren't (or rather, don't extend to) full embeddings so amenability doesn't even make sense. I think the default should be that "elementary embedding" means exactly that.

Comment: And re: context, I don't see how "elementary embedding $L\rightarrow L$" is any clearer than "elementary embedding $M\rightarrow M$" - if anything, the latter to me emphasizes *more* that the model we're looking at is probably a small fragment of the true universe.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm actually interested in the case where A is not a set in M--I will edit my question to make this clear.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Hi Noah, I was thinking about this again and got a question. If A is a set of atoms and $f$ is a bijection from A to some small $\alpha$, I can only see that j[A]=j(A).  Am I missing something?